# Looping through ajax async without using asyc false

Tags: javascript, jquery

My browser and animation freezes when I run $ajax async false.
is there another way where I can loop all the ajax asynchronously each?

```
$( ".checkbkox" ).each(function() {
    var me = $(this);

    if(me.is(':checked')){
    //display loader
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "editor/change",
            async : false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {hmtl: html},
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success){
                    //a bunch of actions to process data

                }                   
            }
        });     
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm surprised `async: false` still works on your browser.. I thought browsers stopped supporting synchronous AJAX. Or is that still just "deprecated"?

Comment: still works. but trying to figure out how to loop this correctly.

Comment: Using `async: false` forces the update loop to block (stopping any DOM changes eg. animations). You would be better to re-architect your code to avoid the use - I can't give a suggested fix without more code.